# Why isn't the creator of a Snowflake temp table its owner?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm running the following code. As you can see I'm using a role called owner_bi_db to create a temporary table.

```
use database bi_db;
use schema [my_schema];

use role accountadmin;
drop table if exists _test;

use role owner_bi_db;
create temporary table _test as select 1 as t;

use role accountadmin;
show tables like '_test';
```

Even though owner_bi_db was the creator of the temporary table, the owner ends up being DEV_ROLE. How is that possible? I thought ownership was always granted to the creator of the object. This is the same whether I do it on a temporary or a regular table.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Ah! I found it. We had a future *ownership* grant on the schema for tables which was overriding the create grant. Interesting.

[image]